# Silent installation of Digitalroute mediation zone

Tags: running-other-programs

Has anyone installed Digitalroute's mediation zone silently or automated it? Can it be done?
I have to automate the installation using command line ( I cant use GUI). Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MediationZone has server installations and desktop clients (the client has a GUI). Modern versions of MediationZone will allow you to install both the server and client in silent / headless mode.

- The server is installed via setup.sh, which is scriptable. Try `./setup.sh help` for instructions.
- The client has a GUI installer wizard, which can be run silently by invoking it from command line or script and providing a config file. You can create this config file by running the wizard in GUI-mode once. At the final step, you'll be able to generate a config file to automate the installation you just performed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to look into installation by using Ansible Playbook.